# Show only right and bottom parts of a shadow

Tags: css, shadow

How to show only `right` and `bottom` parts of a shadow?

I know `box-shadow` can set a bottom. but how to set in `-webkit-box-shadow` and `-moz-box-shadow`?

`box-shadow-bottom: 0px 4px 4px black;`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

box-shadow:

first argument: bottom offset, second: right offset, third: blur, fourth: color
for -moz and -webkit it's the same. So for a bottom right shadow of 4px with 4px blur:

```
-moz-box-shadow-bottom: 4px 4px 4px black;
-webkit-box-shadow-bottom: 4px 4px 4px black;
box-shadow-bottom: 4px 4px 4px black;
```

Answer (score 24):

The same way I am pretty sure:

```
-moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #222;
-webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #222;
box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #222;
```